# PHP imap_list() shows only INBOX and no other folders

Tags: php, office365, imap

When running the PHP code below I get only one folder, the INBOX.

```
<?php
$server = '{outlook.office365.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}';
$connection = imap_open($server, 'user@domain.com', 'XXXXX');
$mailboxes = imap_list($connection, $server, '*');
var_dump($mailboxes);
?>
```

Ouput:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(57) "{outlook.office365.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate- cert}INBOX" }
```

While there do exist **multiple standard and custom folders**. In fact, I want to move emails from the INBOX to the trash folder. But I can not even find the correct name of the trash folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folders are not available in the POP3 protocol.  You must connect using IMAP.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a try with that. If it's working I'll tick your answer ;-)

Comment: Yes! I love stack overflow! :-)